# Spring Secutirty hasRole Always Return 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to restrict access to an endpoint based on roles. I searched here on stackoverflow for a solution and tried a few but was not successful in solving my problem. I tried to make the restriction both in the global configuration (WebSecurityConfig) and also with PreAuthorize Annotation, both returned 403 when called. My test user has the SYS_ADMIN role, I have already validated this flow and it actually has the role. Below are my sources.

Global WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        httpSecurity.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/spring-security-rest/**").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/authentication/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/persons/**").hasRole("SYS_ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/roles/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs",
                "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Person Controller

```
package br.com.aquamain.backend.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.aquamain.backend.exception.InvalidPersonException;
import br.com.aquamain.backend.model.CustomPage;
import br.com.aquamain.backend.model.Person;
import br.com.aquamain.backend.service.PersonService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/persons")
@Api(tags = "Persons")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;
    
    ...

    @PostMapping(path = "new", consumes = "application/json")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create a new person.")
    public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody Person person) {
        try {
            CustomPage<Person> persons = this.personService.save(person);
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomPage<Person>>(persons, HttpStatus.CREATED);         
        } catch (InvalidPersonException error) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(error.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Role Model

```
package br.com.aquamain.backend.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@Table(name = "AQUARIUM_MAINTANCE_MONITOR_ROLE")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_ROLE", nullable = false, precision = 9, scale = 0)
    private Integer id;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"roles"})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<User> users;
    
    @Column(name = "CODE_ROLE", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String code;
    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION_ROLE", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "NAME_ROLE", nullable = true, length = 255)
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Update:
JwtRequestFilter

```
package br.com.aquamain.backend.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import br.com.aquamain.backend.security.service.JwtUserDetailsService;
import br.com.aquamain.backend.security.utils.JwtTokenUtils;
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtils jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Log:

```
[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/**', OPTIONS], Filters=[]] (1/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/swagger-ui.html/**'], Filters=[]] (2/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/configuration/**'], Filters=[]] (3/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/swagger-resources/**'], Filters=[]] (4/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/v2/api-docs'], Filters=[]] (5/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/webjars/**'], Filters=[]] (6/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6d29e44e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@431fc40, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@72dd71b5, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@258798b6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@48124669, br.com.aquamain.backend.security.JwtRequestFilter@4efcbbde, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@293ce7b0, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7879d247, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5e7f5483, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4ce3c16a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@58ad93f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6f778913]] (7/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /api/persons/new
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CorsFilter (4/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking JwtRequestFilter (6/12)
[0;39mHibernate: 
    /* select
        generatedAlias0 
    from
        User as generatedAlias0 
    where
        generatedAlias0.username=:param0 */ select
            user0_.ID_USER as id_user1_3_,
            user0_.LAST_LOGIN_DATE as last_log2_3_,
            user0_.PASSWORD_USER as password3_3_,
            user0_.RESET_PASSWORD_TOKEN as reset_pa4_3_,
            user0_.USERNAME_USER as username5_3_ 
        from
            AQUARIUM_MAINTANCE_MONITOR_USER user0_ 
        where
            user0_.USERNAME_USER=?
Hibernate: 
    /* load br.com.aquamain.backend.model.Person */ select
        person0_.ID_PERSON as id_perso1_0_1_,
        person0_.BIRTHDAY_PERSON as birthday2_0_1_,
        person0_.NAME_PERSON as name_per3_0_1_,
        person0_.ID_USER as id_user4_0_1_,
        user1_.ID_USER as id_user1_3_0_,
        user1_.LAST_LOGIN_DATE as last_log2_3_0_,
        user1_.PASSWORD_USER as password3_3_0_,
        user1_.RESET_PASSWORD_TOKEN as reset_pa4_3_0_,
        user1_.USERNAME_USER as username5_3_0_ 
    from
        AQUARIUM_MAINTANCE_MONITOR_PERSON person0_ 
    left outer join
        AQUARIUM_MAINTANCE_MONITOR_USER user1_ 
            on person0_.ID_USER=user1_.ID_USER 
    where
        person0_.ID_USER=?
[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Id:1
Username:tony.stark
Last Login:2022-04-12T11:14:30.058-03:00
, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy - Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (12/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/spring-security-rest/**'] - [permitAll] (1/5)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/api/authentication/**', POST] - [permitAll] (2/5)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Id:1
Username:tony.stark
Last Login:2022-04-12T11:14:30.058-03:00
, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]] before authorizing
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorizing filter invocation [POST /api/persons/new] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_SYS_ADMIN')]
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.e.WebExpressionVoter - Voted to deny authorization
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /api/persons/new] with attributes [hasRole('ROLE_SYS_ADMIN')] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4f47d6c4], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Sending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=Id:1
Username:tony.stark
Last Login:2022-04-12T11:14:30.058-03:00
, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]] to access denied handler since access is denied
[0;39morg.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:238)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at br.com.aquamain.backend.security.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl - Responding with 403 status code
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/**', OPTIONS], Filters=[]] (1/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/swagger-ui.html/**'], Filters=[]] (2/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/configuration/**'], Filters=[]] (3/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/swagger-resources/**'], Filters=[]] (4/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/v2/api-docs'], Filters=[]] (5/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/webjars/**'], Filters=[]] (6/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6d29e44e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@431fc40, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@72dd71b5, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@258798b6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@48124669, br.com.aquamain.backend.security.JwtRequestFilter@4efcbbde, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@293ce7b0, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7879d247, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5e7f5483, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4ce3c16a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@58ad93f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6f778913]] (7/7)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /error
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CorsFilter (4/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking JwtRequestFilter (6/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (12/12)
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured POST /error
[0;39m[32m2022-04-12 11:14:54 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: Before troubleshooting further, try removing `.and().authorizeRequests()`. You should only have one call to `.authorizeRequests()` in your configuration.

Comment: Steve, thanks. I adjust my code. But still looking for a  solution ^^

Comment: Looks like you are using a custom `JwtRequestFilter` as well. Can you provide it? It would also be helpful if you enabled trace logging in Spring Security (`logging.levelorg.springframework.security=trace`) and provide that in the question.

Comment: What is the name of your role? The `hasRole` will prefix it with `ROLE_` so it will check if your user has the role `ROLE_SYS_ADMIN`. Now if your role name is just `SYS_ADMIN` it will obviously not match. To fix either set the prefix to nothing or use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`.

Comment: Steve I update my question with more information. M.Deinum, in DB the role name is ROLE_SYS_ADMIN. I tried with hasRole("SYS_ADMIN) and hasAuthority("SYS_ADMIN"), but still getting error.

Comment: @EduMarques29 The log says that your user has no authorities. I guess `userDetails.getAuthorities()` is empty. Maybe your user has no roles in your database or your implementation of your `JwtUserDetailsService` is wrong.

Comment: @dur Perfect, that was exactly it, my userDetails.getAuthorities() was returning null and for this reason I was not able to validate the roles. Your answer helped me to solve the problem, I will vote it as the solution and thanks! I'm starting on Spring and Spring Security, maybe it was a stupid mistake but it helped to learn. Thanks again for your help.